# How to stop cpp-ethereum processes and remove cpp-ethereum and blockchain

Tags: cpp-ethereum, installation

Mac OS X, using command line:

How do I stop cpp-ethereum? I installed it last night, and it's been running my processor at 100% ever since. I kill the processes ($ kill < PID >) and it just starts a new one.

I was just trying to use cpp-ethereum, but for personal use, geth is great. And between geth, mist, and cpp-ethereum (eth), I now have 3 copies of the block chain, and no space on my hard drive. So how do I get out of this mess? I was thinking of removing cpp-ethereum and mist, and sticking with geth. But maybe you have another solution... Please help!

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1):

How did you install cpp-ethereum? Did you use homebrew or did you compile it yourself?

If you used homebrew then you would run

```
brew remove cpp-ethereum
```

Otherwise just remove the program from your systems path.

Comment: Thank you. I forgot that I had used brew to install cpp-ethereum. So I sabotaged it, first, and tried to remove most of the files. Evidently I missed most of them, because using your command" brew remove cpp-ethereum" gave me 21 GB back. I really appreciate the help! DW

Comment: This gives following message `Warning: Aleth (formerly cpp-ethereum) has been removed from Homebrew. Please install binary releases from https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/releases.
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/cpp-ethereum`

Answer (score 0):

Now attempting

`brew uninstall cpp-ethereum` will result in the following error:

`Error: Aleth (formerly cpp-ethereum) has been removed from Homebrew. Please install binary releases from https://github.com/ethereum/aleth/releases.`

You'll want to do this first:

`brew untap ethereum/ethereum`

then

`brew uninstall cpp-ethereum`

should work